# Lord created me. Find me!

Tags: riddle, word

> If you remove a letter from me, I'll become a Giant.
>   Replace that and remove another letter, I'll enlighten you.
>   Replace again and remove 2 letters, I'll be your buddy!
>   Replace again and remove 3 letters, now I'll be alright!

Lord created me. Who am I?

Comment: By replace, you mean return to the original word, or replace letters with other letters?

Comment: Return to the original word....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are a:

> **BROOK**

*If you remove a letter from me, I'll become a Giant.*

> This is the only part I am not yet fully satisfied with, but if we remove the 'B', a **ROOK** is a very large member of the *Corvid* bird family (much larger than crows and others in this family).
>
>  <sub>I also considered *BROK* (a *dwarf* character in *God of War*, so the opposite of 'giant'...) and *BROO* (a beastly race in *Warhammer*, though not specifically giants), but could not find something with a noticeably closer connection...</sub>

*Replace that and remove another letter, I'll enlighten you.*

> If instead we remove the 'R', we find **BOOK** - something which can *enlighten you* when you read it to obtain information and get to know more about a story.

*Replace again and remove 2 letters, I'll be your buddy!*

> Instead remove the final 'O' and 'K' to get **BRO** - a slang term for *buddy*.

*Replace again and remove 3 letters, now I'll be alright!*

> Instead remove the 'B', 'R' and an 'O' to get **OK** - a synonym for '*alright*'.

As for the title:

> A **brook** is a small stream, part of the natural world. If you believe in Creation you would argue that the Creator (or 'Lord') had *made* it...
>
>  Not only that, but (as prompted by the OP in comments) *Alfred, **Lord** Tennyson* famously wrote a poem called '*[The Brook](https://www.poetsgraves.co.uk/Classic%20Poems/Tennyson/The%20Brook.htm)*' - hence '*Lord created me*...'

Comment: Yep! You got it! Also ROT13(Nyserq Ybeq Graalfba)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @Ak19 - I have added that in as well :)